# upload images in tomcat server

Tags: perl

I am facing image upload issue in tomcat server outside the war file. My image location is /home/username/tomcat-images.and what is the  url of to access images in web browser.

Comment: Can you add any further details?  Also worth revising the title of this question, as it seems to be more about tomcat than shell/perl ?

Comment: Dear Sir,    issue with tomcat server

Answer (score 1):

You posted an Incomplete questions, anyway, If you are not finding the image url try to inspect with the web browser inspector

**Firefox**

use [firebug](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-us/firefox/addon/firebug/) addson

If you are using google chrome

**Google Chrome**

Use built-in  google-chrome web inspector, 
load your project url and do

```
CTRL + SHIFT + I
```

Another issue with uploading the image, may be the permission issue, make sure have a look on your log files on the server,

if you are using
**Redhat Distribution** and its derivative like **Centos, SeLinux**
check log file

```
cd /var/lib/tomcat
tail -n 10 logs/catalina.out
```

In **Ubuntu**

```
cd /var/lib/tomcat6
tail -n 10 logs/catalina.out
```

- 10 will display the last 10 logs entry

Answer (score 0):

The answer is, you cannot access the image location using only Tomcat. Tomcat is secured so that you won't be able to browse anything outside what is defined in deployment descriptor.

In order to be able to access the image, you can write a servlet code (in Java) to do that, or you need Apache Web Server.

Comment: Dear Daniel sir,   can you provide me link with the help i can write servlet code in ubuntu

Comment: One way to do it through JSP/Servlet http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23458549/how-to-display-image-from-local-path-from-jsp

However you need to be familiar with the WAR file layout and configuration.